# What does "unidad" mean in the context of a recipe?

Tags: traducción, números

In a recipe on a [Spanish cooking website](http://recetasgratis.net/receta-de-albondigas-caseras-51607.html), it calls for:

> **1 unidad** de cebolla blanca

In this context, does **1 unidad** mean one onion?

Comment: Yes, it's just one onion. The text extracted is a bit uncommon, I think that normally it's just "una cebolla, dos patatas, tres manzanas" (one onion, two potatos, three apples), there is no need to use "unidad" (unit)

Comment: Could you add the link to the recipe so we can check how the rest of the ingredients are written?

Comment: If you buy a tin of food it sometimes says 12 unidades to tell you how many products it contains.

Comment: Here is the website: https://www.recetasgratis.net/receta-de-albondigas-caseras-51607.html . I noticed a similar thing on a few other sites too, e.g https://www.mccormick.com.sv/recipes/aperitivos-y-entradas/entradas/aros-de-cebolla-crujientes

Comment: I guess that web uses a form that requires adding units to items; when it has no units, it just uses that, *unidad*. Not a good practice in Spanish, but perfectly understandable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly unusual to see "una unidad de cebolla" instead of "una cebolla" since the onion is a whole, so adding "unidad" is redundant.

My guess is that the aim is to use the second entry of [unidad](https://dle.rae.es/unidad?m=form)

> 2. f. Singularidad en número o calidad.

but since it is obvious that one onion is one unit of onion(s), phrasing it like that makes it look like you were using the seventh entry (maths related)

> 7. f. Mat. Cantidad que se toma por medida o término de comparación de las demás de su especie.

So "1 unidad de cebolla blanca" sounds more like

> Una *unidad de medida* de cebollas / One *unit of measure* of onion

With the (standard) unit of measure for onions being... onions themselves. It's tricky because it doesn't refer to weight or size of the onion, just one onion is enough for the recipe. Imagine that is was an Spanish omelette, and then the recipe asked for "three units of potato(s)" to refer to 3 potatoes. Weird.

Phrasing like that makes sense if we are talking about a know or conventional unit of measure. It could make more sense for other ingredients, but not for items for which the unit is the default unit of measure.

Comment: Could it be that the website creates the content automatically? It sounds weird as a sentence, overly convoluted

Comment: But, even in the "mathematical" definition you have quoted (by the way, in my opinion this has more to do with physics than it does with mathematics), you normally wouldn't construct sentences with a number followed by "unidad".  The only example of "unidad" used in a way similar to that of the question that comes to my mind is  packs of some products that are sold to you. For instance, if you are buying yogurts, you can find "un paquete (o pack) de  4 unidades" (as already mentioned by @mdwey).

Comment: También existe (en algunas cocinas) la costumbre de picar la cebolla y medirla en tazas, por lo que podría existir una ambigüedad

Comment: Siempre y cuando la mencionada unidad sea sobreentendida por el contexto, que no lo sabemos con lo que se ha aportado hasta el momento en la pregunta. Charo, si asumimos que la unidad para los huevos es la docena y yo quiero seis huevos, entonces podría decir "media unidad (de medida) de huevos", lo cual, coincido, sería tan raro como "una unidad de cebolla". Cierto que cebollas, patatas y zanahorias suelen o pueden ir en bolsa, pero no se suele indicar el número de unidades. Yo creo que esa frase quiere decir "una cebolla", aunque sea de forma un poco inusual.

Comment: Sí, @Diego: estoy completamente de acuerdo que la frase significa "una cebolla", pero yo veo aquí  "1 unidad" como equivalente al numeral 1, así como "1 docena" es equivalente al numeral 12, no como algo que tenga que ver con unidades de medida.

Comment: @Charo sí, la unidad es un concepto abstracto, pero en el comercio es común utilizarla como medida: yo vendo el cemento Portland por bolsa, los clavos por Kg, y las carretillas por unidad.

Comment: Acabo de encontrar el textonen distintas webs. En https://www.recetasgratis.net/receta-de-ensalada-de-aguacate-y-cebolla-56585.html es gracioso ver que también hablan de cosas como _1 puñado de lechuga_ :D Cuesta imaginárselo

Comment: @Diego: Interestingly the same recipe (which I've added the link to above) also calls for "1 unidad de Heuvo", and I'm pretty sure it just means one egg. I suspect maybe the content is generated from a database so the wording may be quite un-natural.